# How would I implement the interfaces?

Tags: java

[image]

Given the UML, I am stuck on how to properly implement the interfaces with the "comparable" keyword. Below is a rough implementation of my code. (Abstract class should be correct but interface isn't)

```java
interface Bank{
    
    public void institution();

}

abstract Account implements Bank {

    public static int account;

    public void deposit(double amount) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have? You implement the method declared in the interface like any other method in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `Account` is an abstract class you don't really need to implement the methods in the Interfaces, they must only be implemented by any concrete class.

Nevertheless, if you want to provide a default implementation for both `institution()` and `compareTo(Bank o)` methods you can do the following:

```java
abstract class Account implements Bank {

    public static int account;

    public void deposit(double amount) {

    }

    @Override
    public void institution() {
        // Your logic here
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bank o) {
        // Your comparison logic here
    }
}
```

Your `Bank` interface needs to extend `java.lang.Comparable`:

```java
interface Bank extends Comparable<Bank>{
    void institution();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is clear from both Bank (three parts, a class) and Comparable (two parts, and interface). The arrows do not conform to full UML.

```
public class Bank implements Comparable<Bank>
```

Bank must implement `compareTo` so a class is logical.

That an Account is in any way a Bank does not seem logical (two Accounts being two Banks).

```
public abstract class Account {

    public static int globalAccount; // 'account' in diagram.

    public final Bank bank;

    public final int account;

    protected Account(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
        ++globalAccount; // New account number.
        account = globalAccount;
    }

    public abstract void deposit(double amount);
}
```

That there should be just one global `account` value for all I interprete here as a `globalAccount` for giving a new number to every account.

The Bank arrow I interprete as field. Not really UML.

---

```
Bank islandBank = new Bank();
Account maryAccount = new IslandAccount();
Account joeAccount = new IslandAccount();
assert(maryAccount.bank == islandBank);
assert(maryAccount.account != joeAccount.account);
maryAccount.deposit(-100);
joeAccount.deposit(100);
```